# why style does not have any effect on dynamically added content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sharepoint-2013

I am working on a sharepoint page . where i added a embed code , which will dynamically build a table using jQuery:-

```
<script>
function getCurrentMainCategoryID(){

var results = "";
var html="";
html="<table class='table' style='border-collapse:separate;border-spacing:1em;'><th style='text-align:left'></th><th style='text-align:right'></th><th style='text-align:right'>Pages</th>";
    var url = "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MainCategory')/items?$select=Title";

    $.ajax({
     url: url,
     method: "GET",
     async: false,
     headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
     success: function (data) {
        if(data.d.results.length>0){


            results = data.d.results;
            for(var j2=0;j2<results.length;j2++)
            {


            var currentMainCatTitle = results[j2].Title;

    $.ajax({
     url: "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('pages')/items??$select=Title,MainCategory&$filter=MainCategory eq " + "'" + currentMainCatTitle +"'" ,
     method: "GET",
     async: false,
     headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
     success: function (data) {
        if(data.d.results.length>0){
            html=html+"<tr><td>"
            + "<a href='/kb/BusinessContinuityPlan/Pages/Forms/AllItems.aspx?TreeField=MainCategory&TreeValue="
            + currentMainCatTitle +
            "#ServerFilter=FilterField1=MainCategory-FilterValue1="
            + currentMainCatTitle +
            "-TreeField=MainCategory-TreeValue="
            + currentMainCatTitle +
            "-OverrideScope=RecursiveAll-ProcessQStringToCAML=1'>"+ currentMainCatTitle+"</a></td>"
            + "<td>  </td><td style='text-align:right'>"+data.d.results.length+"</td></tr>";

        }

     },
     error: function (data) {   

     }
    });
            }


        }

     },
     error: function (data) {


     }
    });
    $("#inserthere").after(html+"</table>");

    return results;
    </script>
```

now i will get the related able correctly. but i wanted to add some hover effect on the table . so i added the following style above the script as follow:-

```
<style>
.table tbody tr:hover td, .table tbody tr:hover th {
background-color:#eeeeea;
}
</style>
```

but the problem is that the style did not have any effect.. so can anyone advice on this? and as a general rule will any dynamically added content get the current css settings?

**EDIT**
OK i added the `class="table"` and now i can see the hover effect, as follow:-

[image]

but now sure why i got white color between the `<td>`??

Comment: You forgot to add `tbody` in the html you are adding to DOM using JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You have at least the following problem:

- Your table is not using the `.table` class. You need to add the following attribute `class="table"` to this element you are creating `<table style='boarder:3px solid;border-collapse:separate;border-spacing:1em;'>`. Alternatively, you can just change the styles to use `table` instead of `.table`.

Another minor problem is that `boarder:3px solid` in your table styles is not spelled correctly, but this isn't the problem you are asking about.

Comment: you are correct,, but now i am unable to render a contentious hover ,, can u check my edit pelase?

Comment: @VasHanea yes i mis type it here.. but this did nto fix the white space inside the hover..

Comment: Modify:  html=html+"<tr><td>" with  html=html+"<tr class='cell'><td>" and add in style: .cell:hover { 
background-color:#eeeeea;
}